# How can I have multiple objects share values?

Tags: c++, object, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have multiple objects of the same class in C++. The class has some variables and the actual code is a little complicated so let's say there is only one: `int iMyAge`. Under normal conditions I want them to have individual values - like the objects already do, obviously. But I also want to be able to link two variables of two separate objects, for example, have object 1 automatically adopt object 2's variable `int iMyAge`.

I've tried doing it with public variables and having two pointers for the variables that I want to link between objects. One being the value of the object and the other being the pointer to which value should be used. So I'd have `int * iMyAge`, `int * iFollowAge` and I would:

1. set `iFollowAge` to `iMyAge` if I want to use the object's variable as pointers
2. set `iFollowAge` to the iMyAge-pointer of some other object if I want to use that object's value

In the code I'd use `*iFollowAge` if I want to get the age I am currently interested in (the object's own "age" or the age of some other object it is linked to) and `* iMyAge` if I want to access or change the object's own "age".

But I get a **segmentation fault** with this method and although this is the most elegant solution I can think of, I am hesitant to use public variables as it is considered bad practice.

Any ideas on why that might happen or what would be an alternative solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `std::shared_ptr` for this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class ThingThatHasInt
{
protected:
    std::shared_ptr<int> myInt;

public:
    ThingThatHasInt (int i) : myInt (std::make_shared<int>(i))
        { ; }

    int getInt() const
        { return *myInt; }

    void setInt(int i)
        { *myInt = i; }

    void marry(ThingThatHasInt const& other)
        { myInt = other.myInt; }

    void divorce()
        { myInt = std::make_shared<int>(*myInt); }
};

int main()
{
    ThingThatHasInt a(10), b(20);
    std::cout << "a=" << a.getInt() << ", b=" << b.getInt() << std::endl;
    b.setInt(5);
    std::cout << "a=" << a.getInt() << ", b=" << b.getInt() << std::endl;
    a.marry(b);
    std::cout << "a=" << a.getInt() << ", b=" << b.getInt() << std::endl;
    b.setInt(20);
    std::cout << "a=" << a.getInt() << ", b=" << b.getInt() << std::endl;
    a.setInt(30);
    std::cout << "a=" << a.getInt() << ", b=" << b.getInt() << std::endl;
    b.divorce();
    std::cout << "a=" << a.getInt() << ", b=" << b.getInt() << std::endl;
    a.setInt(40);
    std::cout << "a=" << a.getInt() << ", b=" << b.getInt() << std::endl;
    b.setInt(50);
    std::cout << "a=" << a.getInt() << ", b=" << b.getInt() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks so much! Didn't think this existed already. Two follow-up questions:

1. Does this also work with double pointers, i.e. std::shared_ptr<int*> or would I have to put something else in the place of "int*" to make it actually work?

2. Any particular reason myInt is protected and not private?

Comment: Why would you want to share a pointer to an int? Shared_ptr are smart pointers that manage what they point to.

Comment: Now I am totally confused. Can you explain what you mean? I have just now come across these smart pointers so I might be talking complete nonsense.

Comment: 1. If you wanted two objects to share a value and that value was a pointer to something, then you could do that. But here two objects want to share a value and that value is an integer. That would make things much more complicated as you'd have to somehow manage the life of the thing pointed to. Raw pointers should be avoided when possible. 2. I generally prefer to use `protected` unless there's some reason to exclude a derived class from accessing something. It's a personal quirk, I think.

Comment: 1. So I'd do something like `int * iMyArray = new int[20]; std::shared_ptr<int> iSharedPointer = std::make_shared<int>(iMyArray)` and just make a getter function to get the reference of iMyArray if I want the array of a different object? 2. Got it, thanks!

Comment: @Agiltohr Please use `std::vector<int>` instead so you don't have complex ownership issues to worry about.

Comment: @David Schwartz I can't, unfortunately, due to restrictions given by the framework I have to work in. Should have mentioned that.

Comment: @Agiltohr Then just make sure you set up an appropriate deleter.

Comment: @David Schwartz Fortunately that's taken care of by the framework. Thank you very much for all your help!

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks! I didn't know I could/should do this.

Comment: @Agiltohr You are welcome. You have 2 more questions with answers that you could also probably accept.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo Will do!